# How to find a phrase in a text file and delete before/after it?

Tags: python, csv

I want to looking for a phrase: "delete this". I want to keep only the text between two occurrences of the phrase, and delete everything else.

```
text.text.text.text
text.text.text.text
text.text.text.text
text.text.text.text
delete this
text.text.text.text
text.text.text.text
text.text.text.text
delete this
text.text.text.text
text.text.text.text
```

Here is my current code:

```
import urllib2
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import re

def to_2d(l,n):
    return [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]

f = open('air.txt', 'r')
x = f.readlines()

filename=r'output.csv'

resultcsv = open(filename,"wb")
output = csv.writer(resultcsv, delimiter=';',quotechar = '"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, encoding='latin-1')

maindatatable = to_2d(x, 4)
    if 'delete this' in maindatatable.text:
                stop = 1
                break

print maindatatable
output.writerows(maindatatable)

resultcsv.close()
```

Comment: Also, what do you want to do with the data not in-between the `delete this`?

Comment: just let them, i need only the text which ones are beetween this words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.split` for this:

```
with open('air.txt', 'r') as f:
    x = f.read()

req_text = x.split('delete this')[1: -1]

data = []
for text in req_text:
    for line in text.strip().splitlines():
        data.append([line])
```

To write to the csv file, just open it and call `writer.writerows`:

```
with open('output.csv', "wb") as f
    output = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';',quotechar = '"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, encoding='latin-1')
    output.writerows(data)
```

Saves this to the file:

```
text.text.text.text
text.text.text.text
text.text.text.text
```

---

Using `delete` instead of `delete this`:

```
req_text = x.split('delete')[1: -1]

data = []
for text in req_text:
    text = text.split('\n', 1)[1]
    for line in text.strip().splitlines():
        data.append([line])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic structure with a switch. It should work even if there are multiple `delete_this` pairs:

```
read = False
with open('data.txt') as txt:
    for line in txt:
        if line.strip() == 'delete this':
            read = not read
        elif read:
            print line,
```

With `data.txt` as:

```
text.text.text.text1
text.text.text.text2
text.text.text.text3
text.text.text.text4
delete this
text.text.text.text5
text.text.text.text6
text.text.text.text7
delete this
text.text.text.text8
text.text.text.text9
```

It outputs:

```
text.text.text.text5
text.text.text.text6
text.text.text.text7
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume for now that the delimiters are complete lines. Here's one way to achieve what you want:

```
import sys
delimiter = "delete this\n"
result = []
with open('air.txt', 'r') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        if line == delimiter:
            break
    else:
        sys.exit("opening delimiter missing")
    for line in inf:
        if line != delimiter:
            result.append(line)
        else:
            break
    else:
        sys.exit("closing delimiter missing")
```

The `else` clauses attached to the `for` statements will only be executed if there is no execution of a `break` statement in the loop. This makes sure that various bizarre end-of-file conditions don't mess up your logic.

The `with` statement is a convenient way to make a file available and ensure that whatever happens it gets properly closed after use.

The `result` list can be turned into a string with a simple construct:

```
output = "".join(result)
```